# What's the best way to achieve the following using Codepipeline/Codebuild/S3

Tags: amazon-s3, localization, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cicd

1. We have a `localization microservice` and a CI/CD pipeline per branch.
2. We also have `develop`, `staging`, and `master` branches that get deployed to dev, staging, and prod accounts through the respective pipelines.
3. `dev` CI/CD pipeline submits jobs for translation to localization microservice based on en.json file in the source code (which also gets synced to `S3` in addition to translated files such as  fi.json, fr.json being created from the results of the localization microservice. The microservice may take days to get back with results and so CI/CD pipeline just submits the job and doesn't wait for the results.

We will be pushing to `develop` branch a lot more frequently than staging and prod.

When the translations do come back from the localization microservice and get stored in S3 in the `dev` account, we want to make sure that only the specific version of the files gets synced to the s3 bucket in staging and production, that the corresponding commit/sourcecode was approved for  release in those envs. Any changes made to en.json and thus to fr.json, fi.json in dev account since the release should not be pushed. How can this be controlled?

Comment: I regret I've read that several times and don't really get the specific question - it needs more clarity.

Comment: @RonanCunningham Sorry about the confusion, updated it with more details